# Android SharePrefrences issue

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I m having 3 activities 1 2 and 3 . All activities have shared preferences . If user clicks back when on  activity 3 rd ,the data of it replaces the previous data of activity 1 . I want when user clicks back the data of the activity 3rd goes off and the data in activity 1 remains as it is. Can anyone help me plz ??

Comment: What kind of `data` do you have? Some code may be helpful!

Comment: In onResume() method of activity replace your data

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to store values in Shared Preferences:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,                               MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("name", "Elena");
editor.putInt("idName", 12);
editor.commit();
```

If you are storing different values, you should use a different key-value pair when retrieving the data. Here is the retrieval code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value.
}
```

In the example above, replacing "name" and "Elena" with a different key-value pair would allow you to add different names to the SharedPreferences, which you can display on each unique Activity accordingly.